Strategies for Finger tapping Games in China
Finger tapping games is a local game in China, and I'm not sure if  similar gameplay is played in other countries.
Every Chinese children can use the fingers of one hand to represent all single digits.
The goal of the game is to add up the numbers represented by the fingers by touching them, and the player who reaches 0 first wins.
For ease of description, the mathematical rules are as follows
1、Each person has 2 numbers (2 hands), with an initial value of 1.
2、Both  take turns taking action, choosing one of own number and one of the other's number, and own number becomes the sum of two numbers (taken as a single digit)
3、After a certain number becomes 0, it cannot be selected, and the side whose both numbers become 0 wins
For example, players A and B
$A：a_0= \{1,1\}$ and  $B：b_0= \{1,1\}$
A takes action first. Since all four numbers are $1$,
$1+1=2$
so
$a_1= \{1,2\}$
For B's turn, B can choose $1+1=2$ or $1+2=3$
so
$b_1= \{1,2\}$or$\{1,3\}$，
Assuming $b_1= \{1,2\}$
Similarly
$a_2= \{2,2\}$or$\{1,3\}$or$\{1,4\}$
……
If $a_k=b_k=\{7,7\}$,
$7+7=14$
only taking the single digit，so $a_{k+1}=\{4,7\}$,$b_{k+1}=\{1,7\}$or$\{1,4\}$
I want to know if there is a must win strategy in this game.
It seems a bit like a Markov chain, but it's a bit different.
I'm not sure how to analyze this problem, it seems that when both sides are smart enough, the game will fall into a loop.
If the number of numbers on both sides is expanded to n, it becomes even more difficult to analyze.

What does "sum of two numbers, taken as a single digit" mean? For example, what happens when you sum 3 and 4? Does it become $2$ (because $3 + 4 \equiv 2 \mod 5$)?

@angryavian I can’t speak for the OP, but I’ve played this game myself when I was a child, and that’s how I remember the game works.

So the players start with all four hands worth 1?  Then the first player picks two hands and the one of theirs they picked is now worth 2?  The second player can select their hand worth 1 and either 1 or 2 from the other, finishing with 1+2 or 1+3?  Is that right?

There’re not that many possibilities (for a computer), so you can probably just code a program to solve this. I’ve hand-computed a reasonably large amount of possibilities and I’m more or less convinced that when both sides play optimally this should result in a loop. I haven’t checked everything, though.

Sorry, I have edited it again

I will note a position by [ab cd], where player 1 gets to play and has hands a and b, and player 2 has hands c and d.
By computer search, I found that the game is a draw. Obviously, there are multiple strategies to get the draw, here the easiest one could come up with:
The goal is to avoid $0$'s at all cost. For that, avoid getting one of these positions (you playing):
[aa bc] with $a+b+c$ a multiple of 10
[aa bc] with $a+2b$ and $a+2c$ multiples of 10 ([22 49], [44 38], [66 27] [88 16])
[16 27], [27 49], [38 16], [49 38]
You need to do a look-ahead to check the opponent can't reach these positions, so it is not very practical, but it is the best I have for the moment.
Not all positions where the opponent gets a $0$ are lost, but avoiding him to get a $0$ is an easier strategy to implement. You never lose anything by taking a $0$, in all cases, you can at least defend a draw.
